# Matlab: Count the number of dots in URL

Tags: regex, matlab

Here is my algorithms to count the number of dots in URL:
     1) Input the full URL in matlab editor
     2) Eliminate the path behind, then left the domain part of URL
     3) Check the number of '.'/dots in domain part of URL
     4) If the '.'/dots in domain part of URL equal or more than 3 then return 1, else if between 1 and 3 return 0, else return -1

```
str = {'http://www.math-works.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html';
      'https://www.math.works.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html';
      'google.com/voice';
      'http://m.o.n.k.e.y.org/';
      'stack.overflow.com/';
      'meta.stackoverflow.com'};

out = regexp(str,'.*?[^/](?=(/([^/]|$)|$))','match','once')

A = {'.'};

cellfun('.'(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(out, A{1}))>1
```

I have settle the problem of 1) Input the full URL in matlab editor 2) Eliminate the path behind, then left the domain part of URL 3) Check the number of '.'/dots in domain part of URL, but now having problem in 4) If the '.'/dots in domain part of URL equal or more than 3 then return 1, else if between 1 and 3 return 0, else return -1

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: i get the error, "??? Error: File: f5.m Line: 16 Column: 14
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket."
I have problem in counting the number of '.'/dots and if-else statement there

Comment: try this, `cellfun(@(n) (~isempty(n)), strfind(out, A{1}))>1`

Comment: how about checking the if else statement there, " If the '.'/dots in domain part of URL equal or more than 3 then return 1, else if between 1 and 3 return 0, else return -1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the right `cellfun` command to get the answer.

```
str = {'http://www.math-works.com/help/images/removing-noise-from-images.html';
  'https://www.math.works.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi@dfvfv.html';
  'google.com/voice';
  'http://m.o.n.k.e.y.org/';
  'stack.overflow.com/';
  'meta.stackoverflow.com'};

out = regexp(str,'.*?[^/](?=(/([^/]|$)|$))','match','once')
A=cellfun(@(x) length(strfind(x,'.')), out);
B=-1*ones(length(A),1);
B(A>=3)=1;
B(A==2)=0;  %I am assuming between 1 to 3 is equal to 2.
```

You can actually write a function to create B from A, then include that function in `cellfun` to directly obtain `B`.

Comment: why I could not get the output of '1', '0','-1' for the condition.

Comment: B(A>=3)=1;
B(A==2)=0;  
B(A<2)=-1;

Comment: You should get. From the above code, I am getting `B=[0 1 -1 1 0 0]`

Comment: oh yes, it show me in variable editor there, how about if I want to show the results in command window? 
my command window only show me:
out = 

    'http://www.math-works.com'
    'https://www.math.works.com'
    'google.com'
    'http://m.o.n.k.e.y.org'
    'stack.overflow.com'
    'meta.stackoverflow.com'